# Where is Lucia?

Tags: the-elder-scrolls-v-skyrim

I really need to find Lucia (the orphan) and I can't find her anywhere. Can I teleport to her, or can she teleport to me? This would be very useful. And anyway, if you can't do that, where does she sleep at night? Because that's the reason why I want to teleport. Because I can't find where she is/sleeps!

Comment: Another answer here: [Lucia is gone. Just gone](http://gaming.stackexchange.com/a/267852)

Answer (score 6):

This is what [UESP](http://www.uesp.net/wiki/Skyrim:Lucia) has to say about her whereabouts:

> Lucia wakes up at 8am and heads to the area outside the Temple of Kynareth, where she wanders around, begging all day. At 8pm, she goes to the Bannered Mare, where she stays inside for four hours. Then at midnight, she goes out behind the inn and sleeps on the ground. She gets up again at 8am the next morning and repeats the same schedule.

If you're playing on PC, you can use `player.moveto xx003F5E` to teleport to her, where xx is the load order # of Hearthfire, most likely 01 or 02.

Comment: Sorry again, but when I type in player.moveto 03003f5e it says parameter objectreferenceID

Comment: @Elliescuff If you really can't find her and the console code fails (your error message sound incomplete though) there is a chance that she got killed by a dragon or vampire attack :-( Should that be the case, and you cannot even find a corpse to `ressurect 1`, you could re-spawn a new Lucia with `player.placeatme xx003F5F` (where `xx` is the same number that should work for the original Lucia, according to your comment that would be 03). Note that this may cause buggy behaviour, e.g. I'm not sure if that new Lucia could be adopted, so you better first make sure that the original one is lost.

Comment: Have you tried player.moveto 01003f5e and player.moveto 02003f5e?